# PHP header error handling

Tags: php, error-handling, header

Good Evening,

I've been tasked with launching a URI like file:// however if it doesn't exist or fails to run then the page needs to display a message. I have done a fair amount of research and can't find anything about how to do this. Does anyone know how to catch errors from the header function?

I have tried doing:

```
try {
  header("Location: URLPATH");
} catch(Exception $e) {
  somecode
}
```

this doesn't doing anything.

I have also tried:

```
header("Location: URLPATH");
if (!headers_sent()) {
  echo('Error');
}
```

this will only work if the header isn't sent, say if I mistype or something like that.

I have also attempted to do the same in javascript however this also doesn't work.

I'm stuck, help please?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: You cannot do what you want. It is just a header being set. The actual redirect is up to the client. The serverside has no idea and doesn't care whether it exists / works.

Comment: You could first check if the url exists on the server side with curl or file_get_contents and the redirecting to the url. see http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php and http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php

Comment: Thank you for the comments. This is what I was thinking.

Comment: I have just found a solution (it's not the best!)
`function sc() {`
 `window.location.href = "URLPATH";`
 `window.addEventListener("blur", mf);`
 `var apc = setInterval(function(){`
  `window.removeEventListener("blur", mf);`
  `alert('Application not launched');`
  `clearInterval(apc);`
 `}, 1000);`
`}`

`function mf() {`
 `window.removeEventListener("blur", mf);`
 `clearInterval(apc);`
`}`